# How to force a specific amount of y axis ticks in d3 charts?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 (version 3.5) multi-line chart, and I'm trying to have 5 ticks on the y-axis.

This is the code for the y-axis generation, with the number of ticks:

[image]

The problem is that any ticks value I put, between 3 to 6, gives the same following result (which has fewer ticks than what I want):

[image]

And when I put a value of 7 ticks, it gives the following result (which is too many ticks than what I want):

[image]

How do I force the chart to have an exact number of ticks on the y-axis?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you put string "Chart" above your chart? I tried various positioning tricks, but string itself always looks cut of ...

Comment: I don't have the code now, but maybe it's not part of the component with the chart. Maybe a different div above the chart component.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the full solution, thanks to @Mark.

In order to have human readable values in the y-axis, I rounded the tick step to the closest 5.

```
// y axis
    const ticksAmount = 5;
    const tickStep = (maxValue - minValue) / (ticksAmount);
    const step = Math.ceil(tickStep / 5) * 5;
    const yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left')
        .ticks(ticksAmount)
        .tickValues(d3.range(minValue, maxValue + step, step))
        .tickFormat(d3.format('d'))
        .innerTickSize(-width)
        .outerTickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(5);
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#linear_ticks) (bolding mine):

> A stateless method that returns approximately count representative
>   values from the scale's input domain. If count is not specified, it
>   defaults to 10. **The returned tick values are uniformly spaced, have
>   human-readable values (such as multiples of powers of 10)**, and are
>   guaranteed to be within the extent of the input domain. Ticks are
>   often used to display reference lines, or tick marks, in conjunction
>   with the visualized data. **The specified count is only a hint; the
>   scale may return more or fewer values depending on the input domain.**

The reason `d3` won't honor your tick count is because you'd end up with unevenly spaced ticks or non-nice, non-human readable values.

If you really want 5 ticks, you'll need to specify them yourself using the [tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickValues) method.  One way I've done this in the past is to use the d3 `range` method.  Say my input domain is from 20 to 170 as it looks in your first graph, then:

```js
var step = 5,
    min = 20,
    max = 170,
    stepValue = (max - min) / (step - 1),
    tickValues = d3.range(min, max + stepValue, stepValue);
    
console.log(tickValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks.
I will post the full solution. I rounded the ticks value to the closest 5, in order to have human readable values.